Intermittent Ethernet Connectivity with Google Wifi and Ubiquiti Unifi Switch
I'm experiencing intermittent connectivity issues with my ethernet-connected devices, while my Wifi remains functional. Here is my setup:

Modem Router: Connected in bridge mode.
Google Wifi: Connected to the modem router.
Switch: Google Wifi is plugged into a new Ubiquiti
Unifi 48 Port Managed Gigabit Switch (USW-PRO-48-AU).
Devices: All devices are connected to the switch either directly or via wall
cabling.

The problem is that the devices connected via ethernet regularly drop their connection. The only way to temporarily fix this issue is to reset the entire system, and even then, the problem sometimes persists. When I plug in a device via ethernet, the TCP/IP settings seem correct. It is on the same subnet as wifi. I can't see an IP conflicts.
It seems like there might be a routing conflict, but I'm not sure how to diagnose or resolve it. The offender is most likely the new switch, since it was all working rock solid for years with the old switch. I think it might be something to do with it being a managed switch. I can't even connect to it via its IP address.
Troubleshooting steps I've already taken:
Ensured the modem router is in bridge mode.
Checked and confirmed that all cables are securely connected.
Reset the Google Wifi and the Ubiquiti switch multiple times.
Updated firmware on all devices to the latest versions.
What could be causing this intermittent ethernet connectivity issue, and how can I resolve it?
Thank you for your help!
